# Generate database using another database shema information using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I Want generate new sql database from another database schema information using c#

The following code shows  for retrieving information from database

```
        string connetionString = null;

        SqlConnection connection;

        SqlCommand command;

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        int i = 0;

        string sql = null;



        connetionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

        sql = "Select DISTINCT(name) FROM sys.Tables";



        connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);



        try
        {

            connection.Open();

            command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;

            adapter.Fill(ds);

            adapter.Dispose();

            command.Dispose();

            connection.Close();

            DataSet dset = new DataSet();

            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {

                listBox1.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString());
                SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM "+ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString()+"",connection);

                ad.Fill(dset);


            }
            dset.Tables[0].WriteXml(@"E:\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\ds.xml");

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");

        }
```

Like wise i have to get information from database and  have to generate new database using this schema information.

Comment: This question is tagged both [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server].  Which are you using?

Answer (score 0):

TO copy the schema from one database to another:

1. Iterate through the objects in the source database using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA set of tables, such as INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES to get the list of tables.
2. For SQL server, call the `sp_help` stored procedure on each (or `sp_helptext` for stored procedures). For MySQL, use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE` and similar commands. These return the SQL used to create the object.
3. Run that SQL on the destination database.

Note that you can generate the SQL Scripts used to create a SQL Server database through the SQL Server Management Studio.